# Why does Jetpack WorkManager call doWork() repeatedly?

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

### Problem Description

When using WorkManager to perform the only task, after an error occurs in doWork() and the handling exception is Result.failure(), doWork() will be called again.

I tried to troubleshoot the error through the log file, and I found that the `setComponentEnabled(context, SystemJobService.class, true);` of `androidx.work.impl.Schedulers#createBestAvailableBackgroundScheduler` was called twice. `WorkManagerImpl` is a singleton object and will not be called twice. So I am very confused.

### Log

```
01-15 15:25:01.198  7797  7797 D WM-PackageManagerHelper: androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService enabled
01-15 15:25:01.198  7797  7797 D WM-Schedulers: Created SystemJobScheduler and enabled SystemJobService
01-15 15:25:01.208  7797  7847 D WM-ForceStopRunnable: Performing cleanup operations.
01-15 15:25:01.303  7797  7851 D WM-PackageManagerHelper: androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.RescheduleReceiver enabled
01-15 15:25:01.319  7797  7851 D WM-SystemJobScheduler: Scheduling work ID b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954 Job ID 68
01-15 15:25:01.327  7797  7851 D WM-GreedyScheduler: Starting work for b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954
01-15 15:25:01.334  7797  7858 D WM-Processor: Processor: processing b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954
01-15 15:25:02.742  7797  7797 D WM-WorkerWrapper: Starting work for my_package.service.StatisticsService
01-15 15:25:02.822  7797  7847 D WM-WorkerWrapper: my_package.service.StatisticsService returned a Failure {mOutputData=Data {}} result.
01-15 15:25:02.829  7797  7847 I WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result FAILURE for Work [ id=b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954, tags={ my_package.service.StatisticsService } ]
01-15 15:25:02.842  7797  7847 D WM-PackageManagerHelper: androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.RescheduleReceiver disabled
01-15 15:25:02.847  7797  7797 D WM-SystemJobService: onStartJob for b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954
01-15 15:25:02.847  7797  7847 D WM-GreedyScheduler: Cancelling work ID b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954
01-15 15:25:02.862  7797  7851 D WM-Processor: Work b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954 is already enqueued for processing
01-15 15:25:02.868  7797  7851 D WM-Processor: Processor stopping background work b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954
01-15 15:25:02.869  7797  7851 D WM-WorkerWrapper: Work interrupted for Work [ id=b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954, tags={ my_package.service.StatisticsService } ]
01-15 15:25:02.883  7797  7851 D WM-PackageManagerHelper: androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.RescheduleReceiver disabled
01-15 15:25:02.884  7797  7851 D WM-WorkerWrapper: WorkSpec {WorkSpec: b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954} is already done. Not interrupting.
01-15 15:25:02.884  7797  7851 D WM-Processor: WorkerWrapper interrupted for b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954
01-15 15:25:02.884  7797  7851 D WM-StopWorkRunnable: StopWorkRunnable for b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954; Processor.stopWork = true
01-15 15:25:02.899  7797  7797 D WM-Processor: Processor b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954 executed; reschedule = false
01-15 15:25:02.900  7797  7797 D WM-SystemJobService: b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954 executed on JobScheduler
01-15 15:25:02.900  7797  7797 D WM-SystemJobService: onStopJob for b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954
01-15 15:25:02.903  7797  7847 D WM-Processor: Processor stopping background work b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954
01-15 15:25:02.903  7797  7847 D WM-Processor: WorkerWrapper could not be found for b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954
01-15 15:25:02.904  7797  7847 D WM-StopWorkRunnable: StopWorkRunnable for b278a34c-aeeb-4c88-8f29-71b9c23e0954; Processor.stopWork = false

// Here doWork() is repeated once.

01-15 15:25:04.511  7923  7923 D WM-PackageManagerHelper: androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService enabled
01-15 15:25:04.511  7923  7923 D WM-Schedulers: Created SystemJobScheduler and enabled SystemJobService
01-15 15:25:04.519  7923  7985 D WM-ForceStopRunnable: Performing cleanup operations.
01-15 15:25:04.600  7923  7989 D WM-PackageManagerHelper: androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.RescheduleReceiver enabled
01-15 15:25:04.616  7923  7989 D WM-SystemJobScheduler: Scheduling work ID 07bddcf0-33c3-43c5-ad2b-0dcb1f200e18 Job ID 69
01-15 15:25:04.624  7923  7989 I WM-GreedyScheduler: Ignoring schedule request in non-main process
01-15 15:25:04.633  7797  7797 D WM-SystemJobService: onStartJob for 07bddcf0-33c3-43c5-ad2b-0dcb1f200e18
01-15 15:25:04.634  7797  7851 D WM-Processor: Processor: processing 07bddcf0-33c3-43c5-ad2b-0dcb1f200e18
01-15 15:25:04.650  7797  7797 D WM-WorkerWrapper: Starting work for my_package.service.StatisticsService
01-15 15:25:04.697  7797  7847 D WM-WorkerWrapper: my_package.service.StatisticsService returned a Failure {mOutputData=Data {}} result.
01-15 15:25:04.700  7797  7847 I WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result FAILURE for Work [ id=07bddcf0-33c3-43c5-ad2b-0dcb1f200e18, tags={ my_package.service.StatisticsService } ]
01-15 15:25:04.704  7797  7847 D WM-PackageManagerHelper: androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.RescheduleReceiver disabled
01-15 15:25:04.704  7797  7797 D WM-Processor: Processor 07bddcf0-33c3-43c5-ad2b-0dcb1f200e18 executed; reschedule = false
01-15 15:25:04.705  7797  7797 D WM-SystemJobService: 07bddcf0-33c3-43c5-ad2b-0dcb1f200e18 executed on JobScheduler
01-15 15:25:04.713  7797  7847 D WM-GreedyScheduler: Cancelling work ID 07bddcf0-33c3-43c5-ad2b-0dcb1f200e18
01-15 15:25:04.718  7797  7847 D WM-Processor: Processor stopping background work 07bddcf0-33c3-43c5-ad2b-0dcb1f200e18
01-15 15:25:04.719  7797  7847 D WM-Processor: WorkerWrapper could not be found for 07bddcf0-33c3-43c5-ad2b-0dcb1f200e18
01-15 15:25:04.719  7797  7847 D WM-StopWorkRunnable: StopWorkRunnable for 07bddcf0-33c3-43c5-ad2b-0dcb1f200e18; Processor.stopWork = false
```

---

### Scenes

I need to perform a task that is only executed once every time I open the app to upload my statistics, and if there is no network, cache it.

### My environment

jetpack workmanager 2.4.0

### My code

Application.java

```
// Start a background only task.
StatisticsService.startService(getApplicationContext());
```

StatisticsService.java

```
public static void startService(Context context) {
    OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder builder = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(StatisticsService.class);
    ...
    Data.Builder data = new Data.Builder();
    data.putBoolean(EXTRA_IS_FIRST, isFirstOpenApp);
    builder.setInputData(data.build());
    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniqueWork("StatisticsService", ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND_OR_REPLACE, builder.build());
}


@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    log.info("doWork:" + hashCode());
    boolean isSuccessful = false;
    try {
        Data inputData = getInputData();
        boolean isFirstOpenApp = inputData.getBoolean(EXTRA_IS_FIRST, true);
        isSuccessful = uploadStatisticsInfo(isFirstOpenApp);
        if (isSuccessful) {
            return Result.success();
        } else {
            return Result.failure();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.severe(ThrowableUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
        return Result.failure();
    }
}

private boolean uploadStatisticsInfo(boolean isFirstOpenApp) {
    // Synchronously determine whether the network is available.
    // If the network is unavailable, an exception will be thrown.
    boolean available = NetworkUtils.isAvailable();
    if (!available) {
        AppStatisticsBean.cacheOneMap(isFirstOpenApp);
        return false;
    }
    // Upload statistics
    ...

    if (success){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set the `ExistingWorkPolicy` to `KEEP` and see if that works for you.

Comment: Even `ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP` will be executed twice.

Comment: Once I had this type of issue because I called startService from both the `Application` class and the `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

You are enqueuing your WorkRequest as a unique work with a [`ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND_OR_REPLACE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingWorkPolicy#APPEND_OR_REPLACE) policy. This means that if there is already another request pending, the new one is appended to the existing one creating a chain of work.
The replace part is only used if the previous work has failed.

Creating a chain of work, once a worker is executed correctly, the next one in the chain is going to be executed. This is explained in [WorkManager's documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work).

An alternative is to use the [`ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingWorkPolicy#KEEP) policy so that only one WorkRequest is going to be enqueued.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not the case. Event `ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP` will execute `doWork()` twice in my program.

Comment: In order to eliminate the interference of other task, I have removed other tasks, and `StatisticsService` is the only `Worker` in the program.  